# Skyrim SE modded save game sync

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim, xbox-one

I understand that saved games for Skyrim SE are synced to the Xbox cloud so that you can continue playing the game on another Xbox one. Does this still work if you install mods?

If I install the same set of mods on a different Xbox one, will the saved games transfer? Are installed mods backed up to the cloud as well?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately the answer is no.

Here is what I was able to find on the xbox support website:

> Can I store my downloaded content, add-ons, or arcade games in the cloud?
>
> No. Downloadable content must be stored locally to allow for fast loading.

And by add-ons/downloadable content I'm assuming they mean any mods and DLC. So only the game saves are saved to the cloud.

https://support.xbox.com/en-US/games/game-setup/cloud-game-saves-faq#2cd766837f8a4b8ca11722124db2f812

Comment: Will the save games still work on the next Xbox if I download the mods? When I installed the mods it turned off achievements for those save games and I’m concerned that I will only be able to progress from the point at which I installed the mods.

Comment: If its anything like PC, your saves should work if you have the same mods installed